# Spring Security with oAuth2.0 and form login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application, i am having form based login and oAuth2.0 based login with Google, my security configuration is defined as

```java
http
    .cors()
        .and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth2/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .addFilter(jwtAuthorizationFilter)
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .oauth2Login()
        .authorizationEndpoint()
            .authorizationRequestRepository(httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository)
            .and()
        .userInfoEndpoint()
            .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
            .and()
        .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);
```

I am doing stateless authentication with JWT, for form based login `JWTAuthenticationFilter` handles the authentication as below.

**JWTAuthenticationFilter**

```java
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    //code to authenticate user and generate JWT
}
```

and `JWTAuthorizationFilter` validates the JWT for subsequent requests as below.

**JWTAuthorizationFilter**

```java
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    // code to perform authorization
}
```

Now coming to OAuth2.0 `customOAuth2UserService` does register the new users and update the existing user information.
`OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler` generates JWT on successful OAuth2.0 authentication.
Now functionality wise both form login and OAuth2.0 works fine, but there are few tiny issues I am trying to solve which I need help for.

**Issues**

1. If I hit `http://localhost:8080/login` with wrong form login credentials I am getting a sign in HTML form with Google login as response body and 200 as status code, ideally I want 400 bad request or something.
2. When I don't provide a JWT token along with request, I am getting the same HTML response body with 200 status code, ideally I would like a 401 for that as well.

What configurations I am missing and what can I change to fix these issues.

Comment: /login API end point is empty, as spring security handles it by default, it just takes a POJO as input, POJO has email and password fields.

Comment: @raviraja Why do you want 400 for wrong credentials? 400 means *Bad Request* and is for syntactical errors. An user would expect the form login with an error message like "Username or password is wrong".

Comment: @raviraja For yoiur second question: You could add an `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, which returns 401.

Comment: What is the appropriate status code for invalid credentials? I am not particular about which status code as long as it's not 200.

Comment: The appropriate status is 401, but for form login it is 200 with login page returned.

Comment: But isn't that wrong, how can i force spring security to send a JSON response instead of a HTML with status code 200, the front end is a mobile app in react native if that adds some context.

Comment: If you have your own front end, then don't use form login, use OAuth2 or basic auth.

Comment: Ok, i have removed the form login configuration, but the both mentioned issues are still happening, i already have a authentication failure handler for oauth2, can i have one more basic auth in the same config?

Comment: @raviraja Did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

for 2nd issue you can add
this for HTTP security config

```
.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint)
```

and then autowire the jwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint in the class
and define the JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint class like this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    // they is always a generic message that is showed when the unauthenticated user
    // user makes a request
    // here in this class we will override and show what we want to show to an
    // unauthorized user
    // this is called internally

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                "You would need to provide the Jwt Token to Access This resource");
    }
}
```

it will  throw the 401 error that you want as

```
public static final int SC_UNAUTHORIZED = 401;
```

in `public interface HttpServletResponse extends ServletResponse`